# ofstream reference using string?

Tags: c++, function, ofstream

I'm making a program with several functions:

```
int totalDays(ofstream &outputFile, int noEmployee)
{
string fileName = "employeeAbsences.txt";

outputFile.open(fileName);
```

However, I don't know how to call it:

```
int main()
{

int employeesNumber = employees();
string fileName = "employeeAbsences.txt";

employees();

totalDays(fileName, employeesNumber);
```

the fileName is underlined in the call saying it cannot be a string. What name am I supposed to call the first function with??

Comment: You 're trying to pass `std::string` when the function takes `std::ofstream`. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Could you please help me on how to call the function?

Comment: You need pass the file name also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's declare (and define) the function correctly:

```
void totalDays(std::ofstream& outputFile,
               int employee_quantity,
               const std::string& filename)
{
  outputFile.open(filename.c_str());
  //...
}
```

Now to call it:

```
std::ofstream outputFile;
totalDays(outputFile, employeesNumber, fileName);
```

Your `totalDays` function needs the output file (stream) to pass back to `main` and it needs the name of file in order to open the file.  So, you need to pass these items to your function.

Answer (score 2):

Your totalDays() function's first parameter is a reference to an ofstream object, but you are passing in a string (the filename).  This will not compile as you report.

In main(), you should instantiate an ofstream object and pass this object as the first argument to your totalDays() function.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers!